# Cypress scroll till the end

Tags: dynamic, scroll, cypress, duration, milliseconds

There is the [`scrollIntoView`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollintoview) and the [`scrollTo`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollto). Both of them scroll only for a specific duration of time. E.g. the `cy.scrollTo(100, 100)` won't scroll at all, because the default duration is `0` and the `cy.scrollTo(10000, 10000, { duration: 1000 })` won't actually scroll ten thousand pixels, but only as many pixels as it will be able to scroll in 1000 milliseconds.

So, I would have to put a big `duration` value and hope for the scroll to complete. And my question is: Is it possible in Cypress to scroll the specific number of pixels irrespectively of how much time it will take?

I.e. I need the `cy.scrollTo(100, 100)` to actually scroll 100 pixels and the `cy.scrollTo(10000, 10000, { duration: 1000 })` to also scroll the actual 10000 pixels. The size of my containers may change (due to the variable contained data), so it makes zero sense for me to try to guess the number I need to put in the `duration`.

Comment: Your theory about `duration` is does not make sense. Why create a command that by default does nothing? `cy.scrollTo(100, 100)` is not scrolling because it's already in the viewport. Try setting `cy.viewport(50,50)` (and get out the magnifying glass).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `wait(0)` after the `scrollTo(100, 100)` did the trick. I.e. : `scrollTo(100, 100).wait(0)`.